# How can i evaluate this power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2n+1} \left (\frac{1}{3}  \right )^{n}\left ( -1 \right )^{n} $

it's solved by power series of arctan. is it possible the answer written by real number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2n+1}\pars{1 \over 3}^{n}\pars{-1}^{n}}
=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2n+1}\pars{1 \over \root{3}}^{2n}
=\root{3}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2n+1}
\pars{1 \over \root{3}}^{2n + 1}
\\[3mm]&=\root{3}\int_{0}^{1/\root{3}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}x^{2n}\,\dd x
=\root{3}\int_{0}^{1/\root{3}}{\dd x \over 1 + x^{2}} = \root{3}\arctan\pars{1 \over \root{3}}
=\root{3}\,{\pi \over 6}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#0000ff}{\large{\root{3} \over 6}\,\pi}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Form [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), for $|x|<1$  $$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\cdots\text{ and }\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\cdots$$

$$\implies\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=?$$

Now observe that, $$\left(-\frac1{\sqrt3i}\right)^{2n+1}=-\left(\frac1{\sqrt3i}\right)^{2n+1}=-\frac1{\sqrt3i}\frac1{(\sqrt3i)^{2n}}=-\frac1{\sqrt3i}\frac1{3^n(-1)^n}=\frac i{\sqrt3}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}$$

So, the sum reduces to $$\frac i{\sqrt3}\ln\frac{1-\frac1{\sqrt3i}}{1+\frac1{\sqrt3i}}=\frac i{\sqrt3}\ln\frac{\sqrt3+i}{\sqrt3-i}=\frac i{\sqrt3}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+i\frac12\right)$$

$$=\frac i{\sqrt3}\ln e^{(2n\pi i+ i\frac\pi3)}=\frac{i(2n\pi i+ i\frac\pi3)}{\sqrt3}=\frac{-2n\pi-\frac\pi3}{\sqrt3}$$

As we are interested in the principal value, $n=0$

Comment: ..Where are the  (-1)^n?

Comment: @user120638, please have a look into the edited version