# Evaluating an infinite summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

The question is to evaluate this:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{r=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1} {4r+1} - \dfrac{1}{4r+3}\right) $$

The hint given is that, the above is equal to:

$$ \int_0^1((1 + x^4 + x^8 + \ldots) - (x^2 + x^6 + x^{10}+\ldots) ) dx $$

I do not get how that is true.

Btw, I do know how to evaluate sums such as:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum f(r) $$

But over here, that $\frac 1 n$ is missing. So that's the problem.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635925/how-can-i-evaluate-this-power-series

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\int_0^1 x^{4r} dx = \frac{1}{4r+1}$$
$$
\int_0^1 x^{4r+2} dx = \frac{1}{4r+3}$$

So the infinite sum at the top is the difference of the two integrals. Now

$$  1+ x^4 + x^8 \cdots = \frac{1}{1-x^4}$$
and
$$  x^2+ x^6 + x^10 \cdots = \frac{x^2}{1-x^4}$$

So the difference is
$$
\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^4} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

So the integral is 
$$\arctan(1) = \pi/4$$

Comment: Ohk! Thanks...this one's worth remembering :D